# STM32 Usart1 doesn't work with TIM1 at the same time

Tags: c, bluetooth, arm, embedded, stm32

I came across a problem while programming my stm32f103rbt6.

I'm using TIM1 (PB14, PB15) to generate PWM signal (works great) and USART1 (PA9, PA10) for bluetooth communication.
The thing is, that I can't make PWM and USART1 TX work at the same time. Everything works perfect until I make this config:

```
TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_OCMode = TIM_OCMode_PWM1;
TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_OutputNState = TIM_OutputNState_Enable;
TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_Pulse = 0;
TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_OCPolarity = TIM_OCPolarity_High;
TIM_OC2Init(TIM1, &TIM_OCInitStructure);
TIM_OC2PreloadConfig(TIM1, TIM_OCPreload_Enable);
```

USART1 TX stops working after that.
I'll appreciate any help!

Comment: From a quick scan of the datasheet, I'd guess that with `OutputNState` you're enabling the TIM1_CH1N/TIM1_CH2N complementary outputs on PB14/15, but are you definitely also _disabling_ the regular outputs which, lo and behold, share the USART1 Tx/Rx pins?

Comment: To be exact, those are,     TIM1_CH2N/TIM1_CH3N. You are probably right, but is there any way to make it work as I want it to?

Comment: I'd be a bit surprised if there wasn't, but I'm not familiar enough with that device to give an actual answer. Another thing to check is whether the pin functions are muxed together or need to be selected - it could perhaps be that the timer init code 'steals' the pin from the USART even if the actual timer output is unused.

Comment: Made it. I just configured USART before Timers and it started to work...

Answer (score 2):

Never use ST's structures without complete initialization of its fields!

In your case, there is enabled TIM1_CH2 output on PA9 pin, because you didn't specify `TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_OutputState = TIM_OutputState_Disable`.